# Why dot (.) is not working properly in insert mode of vim editor?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm using vim for python IDE from past few months, but recently a new problem has encountered. Whenever I press . (dot) in insert mode the cursor does not move to next position instead it remains at same position and a pop sound come when I press . (dot) key. This problem is not letting me to code properly.

Below is a pic. to explain problem : -

[image]

here when i write `turtle.` then the problem comes I have to move one step explicitly using my arrow key. Please tell if I need to upload my .vimrc file

Thank's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’d guess that the dot character has a mapping for Insert mode which changes its behaviour. To see what this is, type the following command:

```
imap .
```

To see which file was used to set the mapping in the first place, prepend the command with `verbose`:

```
verbose imap .
```

To remove the mapping, run this command:

```
iunmap .
```

To prevent the mapping from being set again, you’ll have to modify the file indicated by the second command.